# How to display time at MIDNIGHT when converting "timestamptz" format to "timestamp" using "AT TIME ZONE"

Tags: postgresql

I'm converting a column of `timestamptz` format to `timestamp` using the below query:

```
    SELECT table.recording_datetime AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' FROM table;
```

This works as expected for all values except for times at midnight when it does NOT display the time. For example, a value of `2018-12-13 00:00:00.0000000 -05:00` gets converted to `2018-12-13` and not `2018-12-13 00:00:00`, as it does for other non-midnight times. Any clues to get the hour, minutes, and seconds at midnight too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want consistent display, then you want a string data type instead of a timestamp data type. For this you can use the `to_char` method as described in the docs. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-formatting.html

Conversely, there may be an option in your db client regarding how timestamps are displayed.

Something like:

```
SELECT to_char( table.recording_datetime AT TIME ZONE 'America/New_York' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM table;
```

This also lets you decide to include milliseconds, microseconds, etc or not.

Comment: Thanks, ideally I was looking to stay in the "timestamp" data type.